# VBA INSERT FROM a table and also from a form

Tags: vba, forms, insert, dropdown

I am new to using VBA code and am having trouble getting a full piece of code to run.

I am trying to complete an insert into a table "SmallItems" taking existing fields from table "SmallItemsImport" but also inserting new fields that i want left blank for later use, and also taking the 2 values from a form and inserting them into fields in the "SmallItems" table.

SmallItemsImport table fields = ItemNo, Caseworker, VSSID, ItemDescription, Framework, Amount

Extra fields I want inserted and left blank = QueryDate, QueryUser, VouchedDate, VouchedUser, Status

Fields I wanted created and values taken from form drop downs = Organisation, ReturnDate

I have tried the following code but it would not work:

strSQL = "INSERT INTO SmallItems ( Organisation, ReturnDate, ItemNo, Caseworker, ID, ItemDescription, Framework, Amount, QueryDate, QueryUser, VouchedDate, VouchedUser, Status ) SELECT Forms![SmallItemsImportValidationForm]![OrganisationDropDown]" & ", [SmallItemsImportValidationForm]![ReturnDateDropDown]" & " ,[SmallItemsImport].ItemNo, [SmallItemsImport].Caseworker, [SmallItemsImport].ID, [SmallItemsImport].ItemDescription, [SmallItemsImport].Framework, [SmallItemsImport].Amount " & "FROM [SmallItemsImport]"

Any Help Appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It's hard to help without seeing the actual error messages you're getting. Can you update your question to include the error messages you got?

Comment: It does not give an error message, it just does nothing when I try to run it, Adding the Null Values has allowed it to run, but now its looking a parameter for the ReturnDate instead of pulling the value selected in the drop down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By including them in the insert clause, you are telling your DB to expect a value for fields `QueryDate, QueryUser, VouchedDate, VouchedUser, Status`

```
INSERT INTO SmallItems ( Organisation, ReturnDate, ItemNo, Caseworker, 
ID, ItemDescription, Framework, Amount, 
QueryDate, QueryUser, VouchedDate, VouchedUser, Status )
```

however in your select you dont supply a corresponding value for the last 5 fields, so you have a mismatch (number fields in insert <> number fields in select) so either ...

1. Add literal values to your select statement corresponding to the fields (for illustration I'm using Null but could be anything you want)

`SELECT ... , [SmallItemsImport].Amount, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null FROM ...`

or

2. Just leve them out of the insert clause and let the DB create a default value

```
INSERT INTO SmallItems ( Organisation, ReturnDate, ItemNo, 
    Caseworker, ID, ItemDescription, Framework, Amount)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, adding the Nulls has allowed the code to run now but now when i run it it asks me to enter the Parameter Value for the ReturnDate instead of pulling it from the value selected in the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved, after adding in the Null values, I was missing the word "Forms" before the ReturnDate SELECT, after adding this it worked as I wanted.

strSQL = "INSERT INTO SmallItems ( Organisation, ReturnDate, ItemNo, Caseworker, ID, ItemDescription, Framework, Amount, QueryDate, QueryUser, VouchedDate, VouchedUser, Status ) SELECT Forms![SmallItemsImportValidationForm]![OrganisationDropDown]" & ", Forms![SmallItemsImportValidationForm]![ReturnDateDropDown]" & " ,[SmallItemsImport].ItemNo, [SmallItemsImport].Caseworker, [SmallItemsImport].ID, [SmallItemsImport].ItemDescription, [SmallItemsImport].Framework, [SmallItemsImport].Amount, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null " & "FROM [SmallItemsImport]"

Thanks for the replies.